# extract string with regex in scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have a use case where I would like to extract certain string from an input in scala.

My input string looks something like:

```
asdwf:"ssdf", as232:"ss",ABC:"xxx",sdfsf234:"sdaf"
```

I would like to extract the `xxx` after `ABC`.

I tried defining a regex match pattern:
`val Pattern = """ABC:"(.*)",""".r`, but got `ABC:"xxx",sdfsf234:"sdaf"` as output string.

Anything I am not doing correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Your input string seem to have some sort of format, do you know which one? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [non-greedy expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), i.e.:

```
val Pattern = """ABC:"(.*?)"""".r
```

---

**Update:**

I'm not a `scala` user and I cannot test the code, but in theory the following should replace everything with the value of `ABC`

```
val res = """ asdwf:"ssdf", as232:"ss",ABC:"xxx",sdfsf234:"sdaf"""".replaceAll(""".*ABC:"(.*?)".*""", "$1")
```

---

I took a *crash course* on `scala` and the regex seems to work:

https://ideone.com/LAlCc0

Comment: It worked! Any way I can just extract the xxx after ABC?

Comment: @ChengXY I've update the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for matches like this

```
    val p = """[^ :,"]+[\s]*:"[^"]*"""".r
    p findAllIn """asdwf:"ssdf", as232:"ss",ABC:"xxx",sdfsf234:"sdaf""""
```

Now you can get an iterator with all the matches.

You can extract their contents like this

```scala
    (p findAllIn """asdwf:"ssdf", as232:"ss",ABC:"xxx",sdfsf234:"sdaf"""").map(str => {
        val p(key, value) = str
        (key, value)
    }).toMap
```