# Extract the repetitive parts of a String by Regex pattern matching in Scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have this code for extracting the repetitive `:` separated sections of a regex, which does not give me the right output.

```
val pattern = """([a-zA-Z]+)(:([a-zA-Z]+))*""".r

for (p <- pattern findAllIn "it:is:very:great just:because:it is") p match {

     case pattern("it", pattern(is, pattern(very, great))) => println("it: "+ is + very+ great)

     case pattern(it, _,rest) => println( it+" : "+ rest)

     case pattern(it, is, very, great) => println(it +" : "+ is +" : "+ very +" : " + great)

     case _ => println("match failure")
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I write a case expression which allows me to extract each `:` separated part of the `pattern` regex?

What is the right syntax with which to solve this?

How can the match against unknown number of arguments to be extracted from a regex be done?

In this case print:

```
it : is : very : great

just : because : it

is
```

Comment: You can't use repeated capturing group like that, it only saves the last captured value as the current group value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43566331/4621188) method? I cannot get it to work, though.

Comment: Maybe just `val results = """\b[a-zA-Z]+(?::[a-zA-Z]+)*\b""".r.findAllIn(text).toList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use repeated capturing group like that, it only saves the last captured value as the current group value.

You can still get the matches you need with a `\b[a-zA-Z]+(?::[a-zA-Z]+)*\b` regex and then split each match with `:`:

```scala
val text = "it:is:very:great just:because:it is"
val regex = """\b[a-zA-Z]+(?::[a-zA-Z]+)*\b""".r
val results = regex.findAllIn(text).map(_ split ':').toList
results.foreach { x => println(x.mkString(", ")) }
// => it, is, very, great
//    just, because, it
//    is
```

See the [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/MQS25508). *Regex details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `(?::[a-zA-Z]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: Thank you very much. This is doing the job. I just don’t understand why you use this regex pattern instead of the simpler one I wrote in the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user221678 Word boundaries only match whole words (only when not glued to other word chars). If you do not need that, remove `\b`s. A non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, is best practice in regex, it does not keep the captured substring in memory and should be used when the captures are not going to be accessed after the match is obtained.