# Split one row into several rows in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table, the table has all the data of this type:
`03104|00000000000000105000|00000000000000002000|001|00095|000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001835162021-07-15`

I want to split this column into:

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|               03104|
|00000000000000105000|
|00000000000000002000|
|                 001|
|               00095|
|00000000000000000...|
+--------------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548675/extract-the-repetitive-parts-of-a-string-by-regex-pattern-matching-in-scala) question is related to yours.

Comment: `value.split( ‘|’)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the column by `|` to get array then call explode/explode_outer to get the desired result.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
  import spark.implicits._

  List("03104|00000000000000105000|00000000000000002000|001|00095|" +
   "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001835162021-07-15")
   .toDF("value")
   .select(explode_outer(split('value, "\\|")).as("value"))
   .show(false)

    /*
    +------------------------------------------------------------+
    |value                                                       |
    +------------------------------------------------------------+
    |03104                                                       |
    |00000000000000105000                                        |
    |00000000000000002000                                        |
    |001                                                         |
    |00095                                                       |
    |000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001835162021-07-15|
    +------------------------------------------------------------+ */
```